# How can I take the sum of only the max values?

Tags: sql-server

I need to take the max cost of each tracking number (TN) and then sum those values grouped by the OrderNo. 
Here's a table:

```
 +----+-----+-------+
 |TNo |cost| OrderNo|
 +----+-----+-------+
 | 1  | 5  | 12     |
 | 1  | 4  | 12     |
 | 2  | 6  | 12     |
 | 2  | 3  | 12     |
 | 3  | 3  | 15     |
 | 4  | 2  | 15     |
 | 4  | 3  | 15     |
 +----+-----+-------+
```

Here's what I want my results to be:

```
 +--------+-----+
 | OrderNo| Sum |
 +--------+-----+
 | 12     | 11  | (6+5)
 | 15     | 6   | (3+3)
 +--------+-----+
```

This is what I have so far, but this sums the max but for all instances of the Tracking No. For example, in the above table, for Order# 12, it would sum `5+5+6+6`. I only want to sum the max values `(5+6)`.

```
SELECT ol.OrderNo, SUM(t.maxCost)
   FROM (
     SELECT 
       ol.TrackingNumber, MAX(ol.Cost) maxCost
       FROM OzLink ol GROUP BY ol.TrackingNumber) t
  JOIN OzLink ol ON ol.TrackingNumber=t.TrackingNumber
   GROUP BY ol.OrderNo
```

**Also, I'm new to this work and asking questions on stackoverflow so feedback on how I asked this question would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
SELECT ol.OrderNo, SUM(ol.maxCost)
   FROM (
     SELECT 
       ol.TrackingNumber, MAX(ol.Cost) maxCost, ol.OrderNo
       FROM OzLink ol GROUP BY ol.TrackingNumber,ol.OrderNo) ol
   GROUP BY ol.OrderNo
```

Comment: @CarleyGuidry Please accept my reply as correct answer as it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: This is a nice alternative of using cte, looks simpler. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can benefit from `cte` like below:

```
CREATE TABLE mytab
    (
      TNo INT,
      Cost INT,
      OrderNo INT
    )

insert into mytab values (1,5,12)
insert into mytab values (1,4,12)
insert into mytab values (2,6,12)
insert into mytab values (2,3,12)
insert into mytab values (3,3,13)
insert into mytab values (4,2,13)
insert into mytab values (4,3,13)

;with cte (TNo,OrderNo,maxcost) as (
   select TNo,OrderNo,Max(Cost) as maxcost
   from mytab
   group by TNo, OrderNo
)
select OrderNo,SUM(maxcost) 
from cte
group by OrderNo
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways, like the answers below. But you can also use the below query, and create a Row number based on OrderNo and TN and Order by the Cost DESC in the Subquery and then only return the highest cost.

```
SELECT OrderNo,
    SUM(Cost) As Cost
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNo, TN ORDER BY Cost DESC) AS HighestCost,
        Cost,
        OrderNo,
        TN
    FROM TableName 
) AS Data
WHERE HighestCost = 1
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same as another answer

```
declare @T TABLE (TNo INT, Cost INT, OrderNo INT);
insert into @T values (1,5,12), (1,4,12), (2,6,12), (2,3,12), (3,3,15), (4,2,15), (4,3,15);
select t.OrderNo, sum(t.cost) 
from ( select OrderNo, cost 
            , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by TNo, OrderNo order by cost desc) as rn
       from @T
     ) t 
where t.rn = 1 
group by t.OrderNo;  

OrderNo     
----------- -----------
12          11
15          6
```